What could be the cause of the inconsistent processing time of Apply to each in Power Automate?
Assumptions:

The action in Apply to each is formatting the result of an HTTP request.
Concurrency control is turned on for Apply to each, and the order is set to 20.
The flow (child flow) including Apply to each is called from the parent flow in 3 parallel.
Power Automate for Power Apps per User Plan” is applied to the owner of both the parent and child flows.
The total number of actions in the parent and child flows is less than 2000 in total.

Occurrence:

Some flows complete in about 10 seconds, while others do not complete even after several hours.

Verification:

The same problem occurs even if the amount of data processed in Apply to each is reduced (the number of loops is reduced from the original 70 to 5).
The same problem occurs even if the number of actions in Apply to each is reduced to one.
The same problem occurs even if HTTP is deleted from the action in Apply to each.
The problem does not occur if the “Apply to each” section is deleted.


Can you share what exactly is happening within the foreach as certain expressions do take time (even if they are being run in separate runs). Please share a tentative idea and expressions in use.
